# Auto import not including ./ for each path causing error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vite, solid-js

I just started a `Solidjs` project and it seems that when i try to use the `auto import`, it doesn't include the `./` which causes import problems in `Vite`. Example is `"import Dashboard from "routes/Dashboard";"`.  As you can see, the `./` is missing and this causes a  `Failed to resolve import "routes/Dashboard" from "src\App.jsx". Does the file exist?` error

This would be a big hassle if every time i need to manually fix the import in the future. I have tried searching in the internet but its either i am not using the correct terms in searching this solution or no one else has encountered this problem. How do i fix this? Also i am using VScode as my editor.

**jsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "jsxImportSource": "solid-js",
    "types": ["vite/client"],
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",

  },
}
```

**settings.json in vscode**

```
{
    "dart.flutterSdkPath": "C:\\Flutter\\flutter",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The culprit is `"baseUrl": "./src",` in `jsconfig.json`. I removed the line and it seems to work normally.